# Выяснить, делятся ли два натуральных числа нацело (Pascal)

Tags: математика, pascal, числа

Есть задачка:

Даны два натуральных числа n и m. Если одно из них делится на другое нацело, выведите 1, иначе выведите любое другое целое число.

***При решении этой задачи нельзя пользоваться условной инструкцией if и циклами.***

---

Вот то, что я накидал... оказалось — совсем не то...

```
program num;
var n, m:integer;
begin
readln(n,m);
n:= m mod n;
case n of
    0: writeln('1');
    end;
writeln(n);
      //if (n mod m = 0) then
      //writeln('1')
      //else writeln('Other number');
      //readln
end.
```

Как решить эту задачу без использования циклов и условий? Намекните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4):

Можно после чтения данных вывести на экран значение выражения (m mod n)+1.

```
program num;
var
  n, m: integer;
begin
  Readln(n,m);
  Writeln((m mod n) + 1);
end.
```

Pascal  знаю плохо, очень давно писал на дельфи, поэтому код мог написать неправильно. Думаю, Вы уловили мысль, код, если что, исправите.

Comment: одна только поправка: в конце end с точкой "end."

Comment: я бы немного добавил однозначности `WriteLn((Max(n, m) Mod Min(n, m)) + 1);`